# Why does firebase not work on my nodejs server?

Tags: node.js, express, firebase, firebase-authentication

You will see I have this code

```
var email = req.body.correo;
var pass = req.body.pass;
var firebase = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./prueba-064cb79dba28.json");

firebase.initializeApp({
credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
databaseURL: "https://prueba-b81ec.firebaseio.com"
});

firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass).catch(function(error){

var errorCode = error.code;
var errorMessage = error.message;

});

}
```

I have been browsing the documentation, first I had a deprecated method error  with the firebase library, the server sent me an error message telling me to use this one, however it does not work, it does not create the user, I already verified that the email and key are sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are requiring firebase-admin when you seem to be using the firebase client node.js. The client library is used for createUserWithEmailAndPassword.
Replace with the following:

```
var firebase = require("firebase");
var config = {
  apiKey: "AIza...",
  authDomain: "...",
  databaseURL: "...",
  ..
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Comment: You're my god now hahaha that was a lot of thanks ;)